# IOS Facebook API. Posting image to public page

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-networking

I am trying to implement next feature: after authorizing, user taps button and app sends post from image and text to user's wall and to public page wall simultaneously. Right now I can do this but I can't post to public page with image, only text. I am implemented standart methods from Facebook API for receiving permissions after authorizing:

```
- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {

    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound ||
        [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"manage_pages"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now

        [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"share_item",@"publish_stream",@"manage_pages",nil]
                                                     defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                   completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                       if (!error) {
                                                           action();
                                                       }
                                                       //For this example, ignore errors (such as if user cancels).
                                                   }];
    } else {
        action();
    }

}
```

And I think that reason why I can't is that I am haven't right permissions to post image to public page wall. Am I right? Or maybe it is not possible at all?

Thanks!